# MS Access forms don't open on other computers

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have set up an access database with several forms that open either with command buttons or with double click events that are associated  with macros or docmd.openform commands.

I realized that eventhough it works perfectly on my computer, when i share it through a network drive with other users they cannot open the forms.

I have checked that macros are enabled in other computers and content is enabled.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Tried the debugger?

Comment: Trusted location? Did you check the local references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried but the below option, when i faced the same problem sometime ago. I used the below links to solve it.
http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/issue-opening-forms-on-other-computers-352134.html
Hope this helps!.

Comment: That was the problem. I had two monitors and the others had one. I changed the attribute Auto-Center to Yes and the issue was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!